# Node.JS Mongodb query / create

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following Node.js javascript function:

```
const createOrUpdateProfile = (pProfile) => {
    db.update({facebookId: pProfile.facebookId}, pProfile, {upsert:true}, function (err, profile) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        };
        console.log("profile " + profile.occupation);
        return profile;
    })
};
```

The function is called with a user profile object which is just an ordinary object with some user information. Nothing special there.

As a matter of fact the function does what i want it to do. It either finds the profile in the MongoDB database and updates it or it inserts it into the database if it's not found.

The problem is that the profile (new or updated is never returned. I guess it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of Node.

I'm already using a call back function to capture the profile but is doesn't seems to work.

what am I missing here?

EDIT:

I changed the function to look like you sugessted:

```
const createOrUpdateProfile = (pProfile, callback) => {
db.update({facebookId: pProfile.facebookId}, pProfile, {upsert:true}, function (err, profile) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
    callback(profile);
})
```

};

and i call it from a graphQL mutation like this:

```
createOrUpdateProfile: (_, { profile }) => {
    Profile.createOrUpdateProfile(profile, (cbProfile) => {
        // do something with the new profile
        console.log(cbProfile.occupation);
    })
},
```

but the cbProfile appears to be undefined.

Am I doing this wrong?

I will have to look into promises later. i just want to get this working first.

Kim

Comment: Are you using the [Official MongoDB driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) ?

Comment: This looks like a callback function, so `return profile` is probably not being handled. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `return` from an asynchronous call inside a synchronous function. Instead, you can use a callback. Like this:

```
const createOrUpdateProfile = (pProfile, callback) => {
    db.update({facebookId: pProfile.facebookId}, pProfile, {upsert:true}, function (err, profile) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        };
        console.log("profile " + profile.occupation);
        callback(profile);
    })
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
createOrUpdateProfile(pProfile, (profile) => {
    // do something with the new profile
    console.log(profile);
})
```

If you don't want to use callbacks, then [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) are another way of achieving this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me out. I still have a problem though. I have edited my question.

Comment: Hi @KimGabrielsen, no problem! That logic should work. Are you seeing anything logged from the line `console.log("profile " + profile.occupation);` or from `console.log(err);`?

Comment: only 'Undefined' for the profile. but it inserts the profile without any problems..

Comment: Ah, ok. From the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#update) it looks like `update` is deprecated, and you should use `updateOne` or `updateMany`. In your example, are you wanting to update all records with that facebookId, or just a single record?

Comment: If I use updateOne i get Profile.updateOne is not a function. Maybe I'm running an old version of the mongoose driver? My mongoDB is 3.4.4 on linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147734/discussion-between-dan-and-kim-gabrielsen).